# C# ECKey analog on PHP

Tags: c#, php, cryptography

What will be analog of this code in PHP? I am not able to port this piece of code on PHP.

```cs
internal void GenerateKeyPair()
{
    ecKey = new ECKey();
    
    GeneratedPublicKey = new ECPublicKey()
    {
        X = ecKey.X,
        Y = ecKey.Y,
        CurveOId = ecKey.CurveOId
    };
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, not a code translation service. Try to translate the code yourself first, then come to us when you are stuck, making sure to show us what you have tried and create a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

`openssl_pkey_new()` can generate a private key, see the [Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.openssl-pkey-new.php) for an example with private/public key usage.